# PHP flatten array of two dimensions into array of one dimension

Tags: php, arrays

How can I flatten a two dimensional array into one dimensional array?

For example:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => val
            [key2] => val2
        )
)
```

Becomes:

```
Array
(
   [key] => val
   [key2] => val2
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array_shift($array);
```

this will take care of key also, its not necessary all array start with 0 or 1 or anything.

Comment: Accessing `$array[1]` would probably be simpler in that case.

Comment: @Archimedix: Not all arrays start with 1 as the first index, so array_shift makes it completely independent of the key and simply pops the first element off the array.

Comment: @Marc B, I know, but the answer specifically stated `// for your example only` and was mentioned to be suitable, therefore `$array[1]` is just as suitable. Your argument is like saying that not all arrays are stored in variables named `$array`, which is correct but should hopefully be obvious enough. The entire example only works if the outer array consists of 1 element only and is thus highly specific.

Comment: if you don't know the key of the first element: `$array = reset($array);`. In any case this answer is very limited to the array in question only and does not reflect the general character of a Q&A. The warning note has been even removed.

Answer (score 4):

**for your example:**

```
$myarray = array_shift($myarray);
```

or

```
$myarray = $myarray[1];
```

**but:**

*could there be more than one sub-array?*

if so: *do this sub-arrays have keys with the same name?*

if so: *what should happen with the duplicates? rename them all? drop all but one?*

as you can see, you'll have to give some more information on this. the question really isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious way would be to `foreach` over the array (preferrably by reference, to save copying all data over and over), and `array_combine` them into a new array.

Something like this:

```
$b = array();
foreach($arr as &$a) $b = array_combine($b, $a);
$arr = $b;
```

Though as others point out, in your particular special case array_shift is sufficient.

Comment: Arrays are automatically passed by reference these days.  No reason to specify it.  Oh, objects are automatically passed by reference as well.

Comment: Hmm... in my understanding, the wording of the `foreach` docs says the opposite: "Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself". Do you have a reference for that (no pun intended), especially which versions do auto-referencing?

Comment: Hmm, might be wrong then, at least with foreach loops.  You can test it for other purposes though.  You can do something like `function test($array){$array[0] = 2;} $test = array(1,2,3); test($test); print_r($test);` and you should get array(2,2,3) even though it wasn't passed by reference.  Even happens if you do `$var = $test;  $test[0] = 2; print_r($var);` and you'll get array(2,2,3) from `$var` even though you only changed the value of `$test[0]`.  I think they changed it in 5.2 or somewhere around there.

Comment: Damn, maybe I'm wrong again.  I know it happens with objects.  Quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

[array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your keys are unique

```
$oneDArray = array();
foreach($multiDimensionalArray as $k=>$v) {
    $oneDArray[$k]=$v;
}
unset($multiDimensionalArray); //If you don't want to keep it.
```